# proxy target must be an object | reactotron debugger

Tags: android, reactjs, node.js, react-native, reactotron

[image: Error]

reactotron not connecting don't understand why

All things are working fine. The project is running but not connecting to the debugger.
It says new Proxy target must be an Object.

I tried changing port of reactotron as well as ADB but it didn't work.